# get name and id of all text box's in HTML body using java script

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is it possible to get name and id of all text boxes in HTML body using JavaScript. If it is possible please give me a example or method.

Answer (score 1):

You need to learn about [`document.getElementsByTagName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByTagName) and a [`for` loop](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for)

If you want to use jQuery, learn about the [element selector](http://api.jquery.com/element-selector/), [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/), and [`.prop()`](http://api.jquery.com/prop/)

Comment: can you explain the method of handling "document.getElementsByTagName" and "for loop" for my problem

Comment: Try to figure it out for yourself. This is JavaScript 101 stuff. Put some effort into it.

Answer (score 0):

Untested version

```
var textboxes = document.getElementsByTagName("INPUT");
for (var i=0;i<textboxes.length;i++)
 {
    var textbox = textboxes[i];
    if (textbox.type.toLowerCase() == "text")
       {
            alert("Hurray, I found a text box. Name and Id are: " + textbox.name + ", " textbox.id);
       }
 }
```

Or using jQuery

```
$("input[type='text']").each(function() {
 alert("Hurray, I found a text box. Name and Id are : " + $(this).attr("name") + ", " + $(this).attr("id"));
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

So you would get all the necessary input fields. For this demo I'll keep at regular input fields. You can expand this example for radio buttons with the same name or select boxes.

It stores all the properties in an object literal `{}` and outputs the object to demonstrate.

```
var arr = document.getElementsByTagName("input"),
    i = 0,
    len = arr.length,
    obj = {},
    inp,
    output = document.getElementById("output");

// store attributes name and id
for (;i<len;i++){
    inp = arr[i];
    obj[inp.id] = inp.name;
}

// output obj properties and values
for (var prop in obj){
    if (obj.hasOwnProperty(prop)){
        output.innerHTML += prop + ": " + obj[prop];
    }
}
```

Also note that looping over array-like objects (storage of properties) and looping over object literals (output) is a bit different.

Is this something you had in mind?

**DEMO**: http://jsfiddle.net/tive/4JrUf/

Answer (score -1):

Using this:

```
 $('#yourid').attr('name')


 $('#yourid').attr('id')
```

Comment: better make it `.prop('name')`

Comment: I cant understand this is ??

Comment: you could use this to take the id attribute and name attribute out of your inputs